# Columnspan is breaking uniform column weighting for tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I may just be over looking an issue with my code, but it seems like columnspan with grid, weights, and uniform is not working as I would expect.

When I use columnspan = 2 for both of the table elements, it takes more room than I believe it should be able to take, taking from other uniformly weighted columns. From my understanding, the child widgets shouldnt be able to force the grid cell to change with uniform and weight being defined, especially when it doesnt do so without columnspan being set to 2...

Main Class:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import sql
import pandas as pd
from gui_elements import *

class Menu_Window(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, width = 1280, height = 720, version = '0.0.1'):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)

        self.rowconfigure((0, 7), weight=1, uniform='r')
        self.rowconfigure((1,2,3,4,6), weight=2, uniform='r')
        self.rowconfigure(5, weight=12, uniform='r')

        self.columnconfigure((0, 3, 6), weight=3, uniform='c')
        self.columnconfigure((1,2,4,5), weight=3, uniform='c')



        df_display = pd.DataFrame()
        df_display['Index'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        df_display['Time'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        df_display['A'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        df_display['B'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        df_display['C'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        df_display['D'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

        #table = ctk.CTkFrame(self, fg_color='red')
        table = CTkTable(self, dataframe=df_display)
        table.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2 ,sticky='nsew')

        #table2 = ctk.CTkFrame(self, fg_color='blue')
        table2 = CTkTable(self, dataframe=df_display)
        table2.grid(row=5, column=4, columnspan=2 ,sticky='nsew')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu_window = Menu_Window()
    menu_window.mainloop()
```

Table Class:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import customtkinter as ctk

class CTkTable(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, dataframe=None, view_bounds = [8, 5]):
        super().__init__(master, corner_radius=0)
        self.font_header = ("Book Antiqua", 12)
        self.font_data = ("Book Antiqua", 12)
        self.view_bounds = view_bounds
        if self.view_bounds[1] < 3:
            self.view_bounds[1] = 3
        self.column_offset_max = -1
        self.row_offset_max = -1
        self.column_offset = 0
        self.row_offset = 0

        self.color = 'white'
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.headers = []
        self.table_frame_array = []
        self.frame_column_header_array = []

        self.frame_column_header = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, corner_radius=0)
        self.frame_column_time_header = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, corner_radius=0)
        self.frame_column_index_header = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, corner_radius=0)

        self.frame_table = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, corner_radius=0)
        self.v_scroll = ctk.CTkSlider(master=self, orientation='vertical', command=lambda value: self.update_view(1-value, dir='row'), fg_color = self.color)
        self.v_scroll.set(1)
        self.h_scroll = ctk.CTkSlider(master=self, orientation='horizontal', command=lambda value: self.update_view(value, dir='col'), fg_color = self.color)
        self.h_scroll.set(0)
        self.button_settings = ctk.CTkButton(master=self, text='\u2699', font=self.font_header, text_color='black', fg_color='gray', corner_radius=0)

        if self.dataframe is not None:
            self.selected_cols = self.dataframe.columns.tolist()
            self.selected_cols.remove('Time')
            self.selected_cols.remove('Index')
            self.setup_table_data()

    def setup_table_data(self):
        self.table_frame_array = []
        self.frame_column_header_array = []
        num_rows = min(len(self.dataframe[self.selected_cols[-1]]), self.view_bounds[0])
        num_columns = min(len(self.selected_cols), self.view_bounds[1])-2

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 2, uniform='r')
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight = 16, uniform='r')
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight = 1, uniform='r')


        z = lcm(num_columns+2, 19)
        x = z * (num_columns+2) / 19
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = int(z), uniform='c')
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight = int(z), uniform='c')
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight = int(z*num_columns), uniform='c')
        self.columnconfigure(3, weight = int(x), uniform='c')

        self.frame_column_header.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.frame_table.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.v_scroll.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='ns')
        self.h_scroll.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='ew')
        self.button_settings.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='nsew')

        self.frame_column_time_header.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.frame_column_time_header.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='r')
        self.frame_column_time_header.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='c')

        self.frame_column_index_header.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.frame_column_index_header.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='r')
        self.frame_column_index_header.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='c')

        self.frame_column_header.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='r')
        self.frame_column_header.columnconfigure(tuple(x for x in range(num_columns)), weight=1, uniform='c')
        self.frame_table.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='r')
        self.frame_table.columnconfigure(tuple(x for x in range(num_columns)), weight=1, uniform='c')
        self.set_offset_range()

        self.label_time = ctk.CTkLabel(self.frame_column_time_header, text='Time', fg_color=self.color, font=self.font_header)
        self.label_time.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)

        self.label_index = ctk.CTkLabel(self.frame_column_index_header, text='Index', fg_color=self.color, font=self.font_header)
        self.label_index.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)

        self.frame_column_time = CTkTableColumn(self, 'Time', self.dataframe['Time'], self.row_offset, num_rows, self.color, self.font_data)
        self.frame_column_time.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.frame_column_index = CTkTableColumn(self, 'Index', self.dataframe['Index'], self.row_offset, num_rows,self.color, self.font_data)
        self.frame_column_index.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')


        for i in range(num_columns):
            # color = f"#{random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF):06x}"
            frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.frame_column_header, corner_radius=0)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=i, sticky='nsew')
            frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='r')
            frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='c')

            self.frame_column_header_array.append(ctk.CTkLabel(frame, text=self.selected_cols[i+self.column_offset], fg_color=self.color, font=self.font_header))
            self.frame_column_header_array[-1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)

            self.table_frame_array.append(CTkTableColumn(self.frame_table, self.selected_cols[i+self.column_offset],  self.dataframe[self.selected_cols[i+self.column_offset]], self.row_offset, num_rows, self.color, self.font_data))
            self.table_frame_array[-1].grid(row=0, column=i, sticky='nsew')

    def update_table(self):
        num_rows = min(len(self.dataframe[self.selected_cols[-1]]), self.view_bounds[0])
        num_columns = min(len(self.selected_cols), self.view_bounds[1])-2

        for table_column in [self.frame_column_time, self.frame_column_index]:
            data = self.dataframe[table_column.header]
            for j in range(num_rows):
                text = ''
                if j + self.row_offset < len(data):
                    if table_column.header == 'Index':
                        text = str(int(data[j + self.row_offset]))
                    else:
                        try:
                            text = str(signif(data[j + self.row_offset], 4))
                        except:
                            text = str(data[j + self.row_offset])
                table_column.array_labels[j].configure(text=text.replace(' ', '\n'))


        for i in range(num_columns):
            self.frame_column_header_array[i].configure(text = self.selected_cols[i+self.column_offset])
            data = self.dataframe[self.selected_cols[i+self.column_offset]]
            for j in range(num_rows):
                text = ''
                if j + self.row_offset < len(data):
                    if self.table_frame_array[i].header == 'Index':
                        text = int(data[j + self.row_offset])
                    else:
                        try:
                            text = str(signif(data[j + self.row_offset], 4))
                        except:
                            text = str(data[i + self.row_offset])
                self.table_frame_array[i].array_labels[j].configure(text=text.replace(' ', '\n'))

    def update_view(self, value, dir):
        row_offset = round(value*self.row_offset_max)
        column_offset = self.column_offset
        if dir == 'col':
            column_offset = round(value*self.column_offset_max)
            row_offset = self.row_offset

        if row_offset != self.row_offset or column_offset!= self.column_offset:
            self.row_offset = row_offset
            self.column_offset = column_offset
            self.update_table()

    def set_offset_range(self):
        self.row_offset_max = len(self.dataframe[self.selected_cols[0]]) - self.view_bounds[0]
        self.column_offset_max = len(self.selected_cols) - self.view_bounds[1] + 2



class CTkTableColumn(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, header, data, offset, num_rows, color, font):
        super().__init__(master, corner_radius=0)
        self.header = header
        self.array_frames = []
        self.array_labels = []

        self.rowconfigure(tuple(x for x in range(num_rows)), weight=1, uniform='r')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='c')

        for i in range(num_rows):
            text = ''
            if i+offset < len(data):
                if header == 'Index':
                    text = str(int(data[i+offset]))
                else:
                    try:
                        text = str(signif(data[i+offset], 4))
                    except:
                        text = str(data[i+offset])
            self.array_frames.append(ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, corner_radius=0))
            self.array_frames[-1].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            self.array_frames[-1].rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='r')
            self.array_frames[-1].columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='c')

            self.array_labels.append(ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.array_frames[-1], text=text.replace(' ', '\n'), anchor='center', fg_color=color, font=font))
            self.array_labels[-1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)

def signif(arr, p):
    flag = False
    if isinstance(arr, np.ndarray):
        arr = arr.tolist()
    if not isinstance(arr, list):
        arr = [arr]
        flag = True

    arr_out = []
    for x in arr:
        x_positive = np.where(np.isfinite(x) & (x != 0), np.abs(x), 10**(p-1))
        mags = 10 ** (p - 1 - np.floor(np.log10(x_positive)))
        x = np.round(x * mags) / mags
        arr_out.append(np.format_float_positional(x, precision=p, unique=False, fractional=False, trim='k'))
    if flag:
        return arr_out[0]
    else:
        return np.asarray(arr_out)


def lcm(a, b):
    return abs(a * b) // math.gcd(a, b)
```

Expected Behavior:
[image: Expected Behavior]

Columnspan = 2 for table 1 and table 2:
[image: Columnspan = 2 for table 1 and table 2]

Columnpan = 2 for table 1, and columnspan = 1 for table 2:
[image: Columnpan = 2 for table 1, and columnspan = 1 for table 2]

Comment: commenting out:
self.button_settings.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='nsew')
causes the behavior to work as expected, although I have no idea why this widget would be causing this behavior for its parent widget.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page while searching for a solution to this problem:
[Odd interaction between grid_propagate and columnspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73411624/odd-interaction-between-grid-propagate-and-columnspan)

This behavior seems like an oversight in tkinter in my opinion, but setting the width and height of the widget to zero at creation where the button is placed seems to be a working solution. Interestingly, the issue persisted with a frame as well unless the height and width were also set to zero at creation. Also, wrapping the button in a frame with unspecified height and width for both the button and frame and propagation set to False did not work.